# Increase /tmp size CentOS

Tags: linux, centos-5

new to Linux here. Can anyone explain me how to increase the size of /tmp?

I was able to increse the size of /dev/mapper/vg00-usr, var and home , but how can I do if the /tmp folder is shown as "none". See my pic. Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: That looks like the output of the `df` command.  What does `mount` output?  (I'm looking for `/tmp`'s filesystem type.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CentOS use `tmpfs` for `/tmp`. Check your `/etc/fstab` for a line like this :

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs size=4g 0 0
```

and change the size accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for this info for debian and found this thread after some more digging I just found the solution, just to note how it works here.
To use disk instead of ram for tmpsfs edit /etc/default/rcS and set this:

> RAMTMP=no

To increase the size of tmp there's another file (/etc/default/tmpfs) you can use

> TMP_SIZE=2G

Part of this information have been extracted from [here](http://www.mentby.com/Group/debian-user/how-to-increase-space-for-tmpfs-tmp.html)

Comment: CentOS, Karl !!! Centos....